# Extend JASMINE matchers with error messages

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

How to extend JASMINE matchers with custom error messages to be throws when not match.

I need something like this:

```
expect(expected)
    .toEqual(actual)
    .throw('Objects are not equal. Expected: ..., Actual: ...');
```

I need this messages to find problems faster as I can include in this message many useful information, like serialized matched objects, etc.

UPDATE: solution found in answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found! It is so simple! Just add additional parameter to Jasmine matcher and it will be printed in case of failed expectation.

Simple check (`toEqual` use only first argument to compare):

```
expect(1).toEqual(2, '1 not equal 2');
```

Printed console result will be:

```
Expected 1 to equal 2, '1 not equal 2'.
```

When successful comparison - no console message will be printed. This feature available in Jasmine 2.x version.